# Remove values if they repeat in array

Tags: numpy

I have an array like

```
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
```

and I want to determine the number of non-zeros intervals. I know how I can do that of course in a for loop but I wonder if there is a nice `numpy` solution to it.

The method I am looking for is suppose to "collapse" the array whenever a value repeats itself. So the above array would become for example

```
[0,1,0,1,0]
```

for the sake of counting it would of course be sufficient to return just

```
[1,1]
```

but I'd like to know a general approach that might also be able to handle more than two different elements such as

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,0,0,1,1,2,2]
```

or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to pick up the values when there is a change with boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,0,0,1,1,2,2])

a[np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(a) != 0))]
# array([1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2])

np.count_nonzero(a[np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(a) != 0))])
# 5
```

First case:

```
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
​
b[np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(b) != 0))]
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])

np.count_nonzero(b[np.concatenate(([True], np.diff(b) != 0))])
# 2
```